# Merge values split into different columns

Tags: python, join, pandas, merge, dataframe

I have a dataframe in which some values are split in different columns:

```
ch1a ch1b ch1c ch2
   0    0    4  10
   0    0    5   9
   0    6    0   8
   0    7    0   7
   8    0    0   6
   9    0    0   5
```

I want to sum those columns and keep the normal ones (like `ch2`).

The desired result should be something like:

```
ch1a ch2
   4  10
   5   9
   6   8
   7   7
   8   6
   9   5
```

I took a look at both pandas functions, `merge` and `join`, but I could not find the right one for my case.

This was my first try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ch1a': [0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 9],'ch1b': [0, 0, 6, 7, 0, 0],'ch1c': [4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0],'ch2': [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5]})
df['ch1a'] = df.sum(axis=1)
del df['ch1b']
del df['ch1c']
```

However the result is not what I want:

```
   ch1a  ch2
0    14   10
1    14    9
2    14    8
3    14    7
4    14    6
5    14    5
```

I have two questions:

1. How can I get my desired result?
2. Is there a way to merge some columns by summing their values and not have to delete the remaining columns afterwards?

Comment: Why do you want ch1a,ch1b, and ch1c to become ch1a?  Wouldn't it be more natural for it to become ch1?

Comment: Ok ch1, does not matter :)

Comment: That's what I did in my answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

This would get you the desired result:

```
cols_to_sum = ['ch1a', 'ch1b', 'ch1c']
df['ch1'] = df.loc[:, cols_to_sum].sum(axis=1)
df.drop(cols_to_sum, axis=1)
```

Your problem was that you were summing over all columns. Here we restrict it to the relevant ones.

I don't know how to avoid the `drop` though.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a horizontal (column-wise) groupby using axis=1:

```
>>> df.groupby(df.columns.str[:3], axis=1).sum()
   ch1  ch2
0    4   10
1    5    9
2    6    8
3    7    7
4    8    6
5    9    5
```

Here I used the first three letters of the columns to determine the destination groups, but you can use functions or dictionaries or lists instead:

```
>>> df.groupby(lambda x: x[:3], axis=1).sum()
   ch1  ch2
0    4   10
1    5    9
2    6    8
3    7    7
4    8    6
5    9    5
>>> df.groupby(['a','b','b','c'], axis=1).sum()
   a  b   c
0  0  4  10
1  0  5   9
2  0  6   8
3  0  7   7
4  8  0   6
5  9  0   5
```

Comment: Great! What about if the names of the column names differ at all and you want to merge them. Like Ch1 and Ax2 ? Thanks